# How to use underscore properly in a dbGetQuery statement

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc

I want to connect to a db via dbGetQuery. For this purpose I have something similar to (using SQL oracle):

```
v <- "Variable_Set_Pri"
output <- dbGetQuery(con,paste('select *', 
                                         ' from Set_Name',
                                         ' WHERE Descr = ', v , sep=""))
```

where con is the connection to the db. Running this query gives the following error message:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
                               Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select * from Set_Name WHERE DESCR = Variable_Set_Pri (ORA-00904: "VARIABLE_SET_PRI": invalid identifier
                               )
```

However, if I run the SQL oracle command directly it works perfectly. What's the issue with the above code?

Comment: I think you need quotes around v, because right now its being intepretted as `where descr = Variable_set_pri` instead of `where descr = "Variable_set_pri"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable_Set_Pri is a string value, not a name of a column, so it needs to be surrounded with single quotes (`'`):

```
output <- dbGetQuery(con,paste("select *", 
                                     " from Set_Name",
                                     " WHERE Descr = '", v , "'", sep=""))
```